# How to write the java code to save the PNG with interlaced (1, Adam7)?

Tags: java, png, interlacing

I need to write some java code to save the PNG Image with the interlaced=1, which is Adam7.

I tried to use the **PNGJ** lib to help to do it, but I cannot find some sample code to do it.

Any one can help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like PNGJ is not able to save interlaced images.

From the [PNGJ wiki](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/wiki/FAQ)

> Interlaced images can be read (though in that case the row-by-row read
>   is not efficient), but they are writen as non-interlaced.

Have a look at [JavaPNG](https://code.google.com/p/javapng/) or [Commons Imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/).

Comment: Yes, I also see the wiki from PNGJ. :(
Thanks for your comments. I never check the JavaPNG, and I didn't see the introduction that they can support it.